# Creating my first NoSQL database - avoiding duplication of data?

Tags: mongodb

I am in the process of setting up my first mongoDB database to store temperature readings for various rooms in my house. Initially I will store values for the bedroom, living room and outside every 10 minutes. Each record will look something like this:

```
{
    name: "Living Room",
    key: "livingRoom",
    temp: 17.6
}
```

In a relationship database I would probably create a `rooms` table and a `temperatureReadings` table. The name would be stored in the rooms table and the temperature would be stored in the temperatureReadings table.

Am I correct in thinking that I should just store this object in one collection and just deal with the fact that I will be storing thousands of identical names?

Whilst space isn't a big concern this will be running on a raspberry pi without that much space and if it's running for 10 years then it might get to be quite large eventually.

Thanks.

Comment: What about a datetimestamp? What are you planning on doing with this data? Also, think document, you might want to just create 1 document each 10 minutes with all temperature reading in the same document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need a single collection. However, u can avoid dealing

> with the fact that I will be storing thousands of identical names

by making `temp` an array of temperature readings. You final structure will be:-

```
{
    name: "Living Room",
    key: "livingRoom",
    temp: [{value: 17.6}, ...]
}
```

You can as well add the timestamp for your readings

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Can I just push new values to the array or do I need to add a new value to a clone of the array then reset the value of temp to that array clone?

Comment: u just push to the array